# Why does installing Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS server give me 14.04.3

Tags: ubuntu, version

I need to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 on some systems for consistency reasons.  I made sure to get an iso called ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso, yet lsb_release reports:

```
   ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
   No LSB modules are available.
   Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
   Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
   Release: 14.04
   Codename:    trusty
```

I would strongly prefer not to have an operating system that loses support in less than a year.  Can anyone give me a reliable way to make sure I get what I intend?

Answer (score 2):

The third part of the version number is incremented for bugfix releases. 14.04.3 is the same Ubuntu release as 14.04, just with some bug fixes applied. The important part here is “Release: 14.04”, and to do security and bugfix updates in a timely manner. Once in a while, Ubuntu collects the security and major bug fix updates that have been performed so far and calls it a “point release”.

Specifically, the description is read from `/etc/lsb-relase`, which is distributed in the [base-files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/base-files) package. The base-files package is [incremented at each point release to increase the minor version](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/b/base-files/base-files_7.2ubuntu5.3/changelog).

Once again, there is no such thing as “Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS”. The long-time support release is Ubuntu 14.04, with updates applied. 14.04.1 is the just the state of Ubuntu 14.04 at some point in the past. 14.04.3 is the state of Ubuntu 14.04 at some point in the more recent past; the minor version number does not follow the exact list of security updates.